# way to reduce time taken by this particular code for fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, fibonacci

As a fun project, I started this code where I wanted to find the last digit of the Fibonacci number's squared each time. It works fine but I want to reduce the time taken by it... any suggestions?

**trivia**: I find the Fibonacci number, **square them**, and then find the sum.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class FibonacciSumSquares {
    private static BigInteger getFibonacciSumSquares(int n) {
        if(n<=2)return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    long last = 1, lastTwo = 1, current = 0;
    BigInteger lastBigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger lastTwoBigInteger = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger currentBigInteger;
    boolean isUsePrimary = true;

    for (int i = 3; i <=n; i++) {
    if (isUsePrimary){
        current = last + lastTwo;
        current = current * current;
        if (String.valueOf(current).length()<12) {
            lastTwo = last;
            last = current;
            sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(current));
        } else {
            isUsePrimary = false;
            lastTwoBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(lastTwo);
            lastBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(last);
            currentBigInteger = lastBigInteger.add(lastTwoBigInteger);
            currentBigInteger = currentBigInteger.pow(2);

            sum = sum.add(currentBigInteger);
        }
    } //end of outer if
    else {
        currentBigInteger = lastBigInteger.add(lastTwoBigInteger);
        lastTwoBigInteger=lastBigInteger;
        currentBigInteger = currentBigInteger.pow(2);
        lastBigInteger= currentBigInteger;
        sum = sum.add(currentBigInteger);
    }
   }//end of for
  return sum.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
}//end of function


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println(getFibonacciSumSquares(n));
}
```

}

Comment: So, this is not the fibonacci series, but a new series with the properties f(n+2) = [f(n) + f(n+1)]^2 ?
There are closed form expressions for linear recursive series like Fibonacci's or Lucas' series, but I don't know about series with higher orders (i.e. the square). Better ask your question on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you just want the last digit, that's a classic math twist :-)

The catch is usually that if you only need the last digit, you can ignore all the other digits in all steps between, as long as it's only adding or multiplying.

Your formula is basically  f(n+2) = [f(n) + f(n+1)]^2, and for that, the last digit is only dependent on the last digits of the previous results. Also, the last digit of a sum is only dependent on the last digits of every number you add.

So you can do mod 10 for every current or sum value, and you don't need BigInteger or even long to do that, you can just use int.

```
private static int getFibonacciSquaredSumMod10(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    int sum = 0;
    int last = 1, lastTwo = 1, current = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            current = last + lastTwo;
            current = (current * current) % 10;
            lastTwo = last;
            last = current;
            sum = (sum + current) % 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: is there a similar trick for the case where I want the whole integer? just the last one.

Comment: I don't see any faster tricks. Without the square and the sum there are lots of ways to improve it, see e.g. https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fibonacci-numbers.html
These don't work for the squaring and the sum, but maybe there are others? You may find an answer on https://math.stackexchange.com .